# How to print specific columns in with htmlTable in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown

I am enjoying using RMarkdown for creating reports and have recently discovered the `htmlTable` package.

I use the subset function to create multiple reports/ tables from one large data.frame. However, I am unsure how to print specific columns only. For example, my current code looks like this:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library("htmlTable")
htmlTable(subset(iris, Species=="setosa"),
          align="rrrr|r",
          rnames = FALSE,
          header =  paste(c("Sepal Length", "Sepal Width",
                            "Petal Length", "Petal Width", "Species")))
```
````

If I want to print only the `Sepal Length`, `Petal Length` and `Species` columns, how would I do this in conjunction with subset?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a straighforward R subsetting question.

```
out<-iris[iris$Species=="setosa", c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Length", "Species")]

htmlTable(out,
      align="rrrr|r",
      rnames = FALSE)
```